# Cannot use import after adding Typescript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

So I'm trying to implement typescript to an existing project.

However, I came to a stop, where I get an error of: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Here, is my helper class, which is omitted. However, you can see that I am using an `import`, rather than `require`

`index.ts`

```
// const axios = require('axios');
// const {includes, findIndex} = require('lodash');
// const fs = require('fs');
import { includes, findIndex } from "lodash";
import fs from 'fs';

type storeType = {
  [key: string]: string | boolean
}

class CMS {
  _store;

  constructor(store: storeType) {
    this._store = store;

<omitted code>


export default CMS;
  }
```

Than, I import `index.ts` file to `server.js` file:

```
const { CMS, getCookie, checkLang, getLangByDomain, handleRoutes } = require('./src/utils/cms/index.ts');
```

Unfortunately, when I start the server, I get an error of: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I am using a default `tsconfig.json` which has been generated after creating file and running dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `tsconfig.json` and change `"module": "esnext"` to `"module": "commonjs"`.

Comment: Already did. Even tried on changing ``"target"`` property. Still no success.

Answer (score 0):

This is ES type modules:

```
import { includes, findIndex } from "lodash";
import fs from 'fs';
```

But this is commonJs type:

```
const { CMS, getCookie, checkLang, getLangByDomain, handleRoutes } = 
require('./src/utils/cms/index.ts');
```

I think that's the problem. You should use one type of modules.
Try to rewrite this `const { CMS, getCookie, checkLang, getLangByDomain, handleRoutes } = require('./src/utils/cms/index.ts');` to this `import { CMS, getCookie, checkLang, getLangByDomain, handleRoutes } from './src/utils/cms/index.ts'`

Or opposite rewrite ES to commonJs, but don't forget to change type in tsconfig

Comment: Yea, I thought the same. However, ``server.js`` is a NodeJS file, hence, it won't let me use ``import``

Comment: I think I need to rewrite my ``index.tx`` to work with the ``require`` stuff However, when I do that it shows the next error of ``type is not defined`` (refering to ``index.ts`` types)

Comment: Does your tsconfig locate in root directory?

Comment: Yes, together with the package.json file

Comment: Oh, your index file is TypeScript, but the server is JavaScript, right?

Comment: Indeed, so I assume that's the problem?

Comment: Yes, you can't add typescript in to javascript project without some preparation, I think this [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-typescript-to-a-javascript-project/) will help you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot explicitly import typescript files into Javascript files. Instead, you need to use the compiled typescript files(i.e. Javascript files in `outDir` folder).

So assume you compiled your typescript files into Javascript, then it would be converted to `outDir/index.js`. After that, you could directly import it into `server.js`

```
const { CMS, getCookie, checkLang, getLangByDomain, handleRoutes } = 
  require('./path/to/index.js'); // You cannot require a ts file.
```

---

If the typescript files and Javascript files are part of the same project, then you need to transpile the js files alongside the ts as well. In order to achieve this, you need to set `allowJs` to true in *tsconfig*.

```json
{ 
  "compilerOptions": {
   ...
   "allowJs": true,
  }
}
```

> Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files.

Comment: I think this is a controversial solution. In the production it can gain many troubles

Comment: @Amir_Bazanov It depends on the structure of the project. There shouldn't be a problem if the nature of the ts files is separate from the project. As a separate module, only the transpiled version can be used(a good example would be an NPM package which is implemented by ts and we use the transpiled version).
But if both js and ts files are part of the same project, then it is necessary to transpile the js files as well. With this approach, it is enough to point only to the path of the file, not the transpiled version.